# How to sum the sizes of the files of a directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

So I want to sum and display the sum of the size of the files that are solely included in `directory1` but not in `directory2`. However, according to my code, this is done for only one file of the directory, how can I make it work for multiple files? The code below is where the problem is found:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1=$1
dir2=$2

echo Files that are included only in directory1 and not in directory2
diff $dir1 $dir2 | egrep $dir1 | wc -l
diff $dir1 $dir2 | egrep $dir1 
files=$(diff $dir1 $dir2 |egrep $dir1 |awk '{print $4}')
ls -l ./$dir1/$files | awk '{t+=$5}END{print t}'
```

Comment: `du -c file [file..]`  will give you the sum of the disk space used by the arguments (or the sum of their file size if you use `--apparent-size`).  It can also use an exclusion list (`-exclude-from=FILE`), so you could call it on dir1 using the dir2 contents as the exclusion list...

Comment: @xenoid thank you for responding could you please explain it with a command? So it would be something like du -c -exclude-from=$dir2?

Comment: Please see full answer

Comment: @xenoid I get 0

Comment: What exact command did you use? And if you are using the answer please comment on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Best use `du` for this:

`du -s directory` reports the size used by all files and subdirectories. You can give `du` a exclusion list with `--exclude-from`, so in your case this exclusion list would be the names of the files in `dir2`, that can be easily obtained with `basename -a dir2/*`. `--exclude-from` requires a file, but we don't need to create a true file, we can use "process substitution. Putting it all together:

```bsh
du --exclude-from <(basename -a dir2/*) -s dir1
```

There are `du` options to report the size in bytes, KB, or MB, and you can also ask it to report the disk usage (default) or the size as reported by `ls` (which is not the same for sparse files).

For instance, starting with:

```
├── dir1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file4
│   └── file5
└── dir2
    ├── file5
    └── file6
```

`du -c dir1/*` reports:

```
10240   dir1/file1
10240   dir1/file2
10240   dir1/file3
10240   dir1/file4
51200   dir1/file5
92160   total
```

Excluding `dir2` files will exclude `file5` and so the size should be 50MB less:

```
> du --exclude-from <(basename -a dir2/*) -s dir1
40964   dir1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102534/discussion-on-answer-by-xenoid-how-to-sum-the-sizes-of-the-files-of-a-directory).